How to deserialize from JSON array in quotes
Using java and GSON, I want to deserialize my POJO class
@Data
public class Book {
    
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    
    @SerializedName("tags")
    private List<String> tags;

}

gson.fromJson(userRecordString, Book.class)

from a mailformed JSON, which I receive from the Kinesis stream:
{
    "id": "B09W1W4D2F",
    "tags": "[TAG_1,TAG_2]"
}

The problem here is I receive "[TAG_1,TAG_2]" with quotes, so JSON threats it as a String, not as an array. It should be "tags": ["TAG_1","TAG_2"] instead.
I'm assuming I need to write a custom deserealizer, but all the solutions I found are based on creating a new class for List<String>. I don't want to do it.
I want to:

store my deserialized values in List<String> tags
preferably deserialize other fields using default serialization, so I don't want to deserialize the whole class manually.
use the deserializer only for this specific class, but not for every class which has a List<String>.

Is there any solution to this?

@njzk2 the provided approach involves creating a custom class, which is used to deserialize the object. I dont' want to create any custom classes for my field in POJO, but I want to continue using List<String> tags. I also want to use the deserializer only for the single class, but not for every class which has a list. These two points are different, and I have already metioned them in my question

I'm only wondering why you're bothering to implement this at the Gson side if the encoded payload is just an invalid JSON. What if the encoded payload is something else but not a "something that looks like JSON" -- if so, would you make Gson then deserialize a thing that is not a JSON? Why?

@terrorrussia-keeps-killing, Unfortunatelly, I can not modify the system, that produce events for me, and I have to process what I receive

I understand that and I'd have no other choice either. I'm saying that Gson itself should not be responsible for processing quirks produced at the server-side. Having that said, I'd proceed with post-processing the JSON deserialization outcome and fix it an intermediate layer: it's actually deserialization from other format JSON encodes. Also, any implementation of JsonDeserializer degrades the performance because it builds intermediate trees (if you still disagree with the first point and you're okay with your design, consider migrating to a TypeAdapter implementation).

TypeAdapter does something different. It deserializes into a new class, which I want to avoid, as I want to have the possibitility to return List<String>. I also want to avoid something like getBooks().getTagsHolder().getTags(). I'm fine with post-processing, but the only thing, that comes to my mind is to serialize the JSON into a string, and modify a getter to be Arrays.asList(json.getAsString().split(",")) . But to avoid doing this every time, I need to store the parsed value into my books class and first check from the getter, if it's already parsed.

I dont quite get it, how the above option is better than moving the same code into a JsonDeserializer (except the performance, maybe),  as a JsonDeserializer is used to deserialize a JSON manually, and this is exactly what I do (I agree here that I'm lucky that GSON parses that for me). If the option from my previous answer is not what you suggest - could you please clarify what do you mean with post-processing

I added the CommaSeparatedTypeAdapter example to your answer as a code playground since I didn't want to derive it all in an answer (sorry for intruding your answer, please feel free to revert it). This type adapter can also be specified in the @JsonAdapter annotation and why it's more performant is that it can generate and parse JSON token stream without having intermediate representation: in fact, JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer work on top of type adapters and the only thing they do is serializing from and deserializing to JsonElement instances.

By post-processing I mean a two-layer deserialization component that encapsulates both Gson/JSON and the server side quirks parsing itself. Of course it would need more data classes: one for Gson->quirks with tags as string, and one for the quirks->app with tags as list where mapping could be simplified with MapStruct or whatever else and not requring and Gson dependecies at all. Sure, it's really more code and makes the currently simpler thing more complicated, but can ease adding more quirks processing in the future if the server side goes crazy. In any case, you choose.

I found out that @JsonAdapter(BookDeserializer.class) solves my problem!
@Data
public class Book {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("tags")
    @JsonAdapter(TagsDeserializer.class)
    private List<String> tags;


    public static class TagsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<String>> {
        @Override
        public List<String> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {
            if (json.isJsonNull()) {
                return null;
            }
            if (json.isJsonNull()) {
                return null;
            }

            List<String> reasons = new ArrayList<>();
            JsonArray jsonArray = JsonParser.parseString(json.getAsString()).getAsJsonArray();
            for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
                reasons.add(element.getAsString());
            }
            return reasons;
        }
    }
}


Another solution that was proposed in the comments is to use a TypeAdapter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
private static final class CommaSeparatedTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<List<String>> {

    private static final Pattern commaPattern = Pattern.compile(",");

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public List<String> read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken jsonToken = in.peek();
        if ( jsonToken == JsonToken.NULL ) {
            return null;
        }
        final String rawTagsEnvelope = in.nextString();
        final String rawTags = rawTagsEnvelope.substring(1, rawTagsEnvelope.length() - 1);
        // OR if it's not guaranteed to follow the `[foo,bar,baz]` syntax or may contain unescaped `,`
        // then set JsonReader temporarily to the lenient mode and revert is to the original mode in the `finally`
        // -- in any case, abstain from using the lenient mode as it is now deprecated
        return Arrays.asList(commaPattern.split(rawTags));
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<String> value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}


Note that this just works because JsonParser is lenient and accepts invalid JSON. Depending on the format of tags, an easier (and maybe more correct) solution would be to just do: return Arrays.asList(json.getAsString().split(","))

Mate really, my advice is: don't do that in Gson as I mentioned in my comment to the question. You're just very lucky that Gson supports kind of JSON in certain cases as @Marcono1234 noted for JsonParser. Once the string-encoded payload changes, you're in trouble in both Gson deserializer (your implementation is not efficient against a single string) and the way how you deal with encoded data in your application. Really, please don't do that for Gson.
